# PHP with slow MySQL DB Connection on CentOS

Tags: php, mysql, centos

After scouring the web for answers today and yesterday on why MySQL is running so slow on CentOS, I'm a bit stuck.

***CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)***

***Derived from Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.1 (Source)***

**PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Jun 23 2015 21:17:27)**

**Server version: 5.0.45-community-nt MySQL Community Edition (GPL)**

[My current /etc/my.cnf file](https://gist.github.com/ornerymoose/94e7069012c8373a419b)

If I'm using the CLI and do this, there's no problem running a query (ie, select, update, delete, etc etc):

`mysql --host=123.456.789.10 --port=1234 --user=root --password`

I've tried to strip the problem down to the bare minimum: just doing a database connection in PHP is even slow (roughly 5-6 seconds). It's the same 5-6 second delay when loading a browser page that does a PHP query:

```
$user = "root";
$pass = "mypassword";
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=123.456.789.10;port=1234;dbname=mydatabase', $user, $pass);
    foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from ens') as $row) {
        print_r($row)."<br>";
    }
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

ens table has 53 rows, for what it's worth.

If I do a `cat /tmp/mysql_general.log`, the two top lines return the following (could this be having an adverse effect on the query times?)

*150730 14:51:51        1 Connect   UNKNOWN_MYSQL_USER@localhost on 
1 Connect   Access denied for user 'UNKNOWN_MYSQL_USER'@'localhost' (using password: NO)*

Every time I've made a change in my.cnf, I've restarted with `systemctl restart mysqld.service`, but to no avail.

What could the issue be? Any and all answers are appreciated. If I need to provide some additional information, please let me know.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** I also have a different server with a MSSQL database. There are NO lag/query issues when using MSSQL, but I'm trying to avoid bringing data into MSSQL and it would be a ton of legwork. I have a separate IIS server that can query the MySQL tables with no problems.

Comment: Can you also post some information about the table `test` like number of rows and the output from `show create table test` statement and MySQL Server version... if you comment/remove the foreach part does it go faster?

Comment: Updated OP. No difference in page load time when the foreach is commented out, still 5-6seconds. Here's `show create table test` https://gist.github.com/ornerymoose/96be4fce7cd6565637a0

Comment: Sounds like a slow connection creation, not a slow query. You may want to rename you question. Also, my php is sparse and ancient; do you have to create a new connection every page load?

Comment: Updated title of OP. 'my php is spare and ancient' mind elaborating, what are you referring to exactly? And I don't think I'd be creating a new connection every time, would I? I just use `require 'config/database.php'` at the top of a php file.

Comment: "spare and ancient" as in I haven't used PHP in about 10 years, and that was for one project that only lasted a few months, which I did most of the coding on with very little sleep over the course of 48 hours. I was new to it then, and my retention has been poor, but I can generally understand it's syntax and the general ideas about how it integrates with html.